# Using a scanner connected to a pc in a web application using php,javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I use a scanner connected to pc in a web page i'm created using php and javascript

Answer (score 1):

Javascript only interacts with your browser, i don't now if is possible that your scanner act as a WebCam, in this case you can use HTML5 api for webcam

Php or any server-side language is able to interact with the server and run commands , so is posible in someways if your scanner device has some command-line way to scan , but keep in  mind this will only work with an scanner attached to the server where this script is host, this probably works for you if you are planning to create this for a home network o company network, mostly like a Web GUI for the "home/company" scanner

if you are thinking to do it to scanning app to the "world", They only way i can think you are able to do it, is probably creating a Java Applet , but nowadays is very common that web browser block java applets

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly with JS or PHP, but you can try `scanner.js`
[click here for demo and documentation](http://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/javascript-web-scanner.js-demos.html)
Edit:[PDF Document for Scanner.js](http://asprise.com/scan/scannerjs/img/scanner.js-DevGuide.pdf) . Just include `.js` and using javascript callback functions to perform action.

Comment: answer is not clear, how can I do that?? any suggestion without js ,php

Comment: If it isn't possible with JavaScript or PHP I think you should explain how that library does it (a Java applet?). Whatever, the cheapest license costs 998 USD...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario js has no permissions to access peripherals like scanners.so, we should go with application program like applet. `scanner.js` using java applet.